# How efficient is MATLAB's built-in parallel processing and assignment to cores?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I'm planning to buy a workstation to run my matlab data analysis scripts.  I am planning to increase the system memory from 6 GB to 24 GB.  I am considering whether I should buy a 6-core processor, a dual 4-core, or a dual 6-core.  (Right now I have a 2-core processor).

Right now I have significant delays in what I believe is MATLAB's built in memory management system.  (For example, a function will take 30 seconds to execute, but tic and toc reveal the last line of code executes at 18 seconds).  I also have some delays due to arithmetic processing on large blocks of data, but I am not doing any really heavy computation.

At this point, I am unwilling/unable to explicitly parallelize my code.  I know some people have extensive experience with MATLAB internals, so I am hoping someone can guide me as to how efficiently MATLAB makes use of multiple cores.  Will it run the garbage collector in a separate thread from the computational processes?  What operations are automatically parallelized?

Comment: You should definitely ask in CSSM, too.

Comment: @ustun - CSSM? celtic society of southern maryland according to google :)

Comment: Ah, http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.matlab/topics :)

Comment: With more processor cores you will probably have a slight (like twofold) increase in performance. With CUDA the increase is going to be x10-x100

Comment: if you have some heavy computation you need to perform, you should also consider working in the cloud, especially now that Amazon offers both CPU/GPU cluster instances.. Here's a case study you can read about: http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/09/high-performance-cloud-computing-nasa-matlab.html

Comment: It's honestly not the computation that's heavy.  I'm looking at experiments where I track a bunch of larvae crawling around on a plate.  Then I ask questions like, when a larva is headed left, what's the average speed two seconds before it sweeps its head to the right?  So it's a lot of accessing stored data and doing comparisons.

Comment: Also bear in mind that there may be license restrictions on the number of cores you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Amro's suggestion, I looked at this MATLAB support document:

[Which MATLAB functions benefit from multithreaded computation?](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-4PG4AN/?solution=1-4PG4AN)

as well as

[How do I choose computer hardware which best optimizes the performance of MATLAB?](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-18C2A/index.html)

and

[Choosing Hardware for Use with MATLAB®](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/choosing_hardware.html)

The upshot seems to be that your mileage may vary.  Basically, it seems like specific functions are multi-threaded, and the list is a changing function of time.

For now, I will just get the single six core processor, because there is a significant price difference and it seems that there is a limit to the speed up from having multiple cores with no hand optimization.  I will make sure to get an NVIDIA graphics card, so I can take advantage of matlab's support for GPU operations, per Mikhail's suggestion and [the matlab gpu documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/bsic3by.html)

Comment: just make sure the NVIDIA card is a recent one and supports CUDA compute capability 1.3 or greater: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/291689

Answer (score 3):

I've got some experience of Matlab's Parallel Compute Toolbox, which I guess is what you are referring to, rather than plain Matlab's increasing use of multiple threads for intrinsic functions.

Parallel Matlab is not a silver bullet, you won't get magical increases in speed of 8-times on 8-cores or 12-times on 12-cores, you'll have to put in some work.  However, as someone who spends most of his time on parallel Fortran programs, I'd say that Matlab provides a much shorter route to a well-parallelised program than Fortran+OpenMP or MPI, in the same way and to the same degree that Matlab is quicker to develop with than Fortran.  But your concerns as a programmer remain very similar:

- (re-)designing your program to expose parallelism; bear in mind that the best serial algorithm is not always the best after it has been parallelised; when you have multiple cores the brute-force approach which was so inelegant and costly on a single core may be the best option;
- load-balancing: making sure each core gets approximately the same amount of work;
- minimising the parallelisation overhead: which comprises both message-passing (if that's the way you go) and thread/process start-up and tear-down times; it's more efficient to have 4 threads running continually with idle periods, than to start and stop them every time your program hits a serial section;
- minimising contention for shared memory (if that's the way you go), both to prevent errors and to maximise speed;
- don't get too hung up on parallel speed-up, once the program is fast enough for your purposes it's fast enough, the objective of your work is data analysis not parallel program optimisation (that's my job !)

Matlab's PCT provides the tools you need, but you do have to roll your sleeves up.  As to the specific question of where the garbage collector runs, I don't know; I suggest your find out.

What operations are automatically parallelised ?  I interpret this to mean *what Matlab functions are multithreaded ?* and the answer is *more and more all the time*, but for the latest situation you need either to test (watch the task manager or whatever it's called on your machine) or read the documentation.

Personally, in your situation, I'd go for the dual 6-core processors and be happy if I got 6-times speed up within a reasonable time -- difficult to be precise about how long that is without knowing your code as well as you do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I actually was referring to "plain Matlab's" intrinsic multi-threading. I was hoping that someone knows what gets sped up by multi-threading and what doesn't.  For instance, I could easily see MATLAB refusing to run memory management in parallel.  Since that's a major bottleneck for me, I wouldn't want to shell out money for an extra processor MATLAB won't use.

Comment: @Marc: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-4PG4AN/?solution=1-4PG4AN